# share a wordpress page on Facebook before submit a form

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-sharer

I have a custom plugin in wordpress which will take a contest answer and visitor name and email in a form.I want to share my page on facebook before visitor submit the form. if the visitor doesnt share my page his form will not be submitted.How can I track that visitor share my page and let the system submit the form after page sharing i completed.  I got a script from facebook send where i can put my page url for sharing.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank">
```

Share on Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this [jQuery plugin](http://socialmediaautomat.com/jquery-fbjlike-js.php) before. It gives you a callback for like and unlike. You'd just have to disable the submit button until the user likes and then disable it if they unlike it.

There are also versions for [Google+ +1](http://socialmediaautomat.com/jquery-gplusone-js.php) and [Twitter shares](http://socialmediaautomat.com/jquery-twitterbutton-js.php) as well.